# Do vectors, that define a 2D space, need to be mutually orthogonal?

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

sorry for this trivial question, but I could not find an answer anywhere. **Does all unit vectors of a coordinate system, need to be mutually orthogonal to each other,?**

Like, they are in every coordinate system I checked so far, so I presume they have to. But I need to know for sure, because I want to derive a unit vector for elliptical coordinate system, by using that as a restriction.

Edit: I think I misused a term here, what I meant was "Does all basis unit vectors, that define a coordinate system, need to be mutually orthogonal". 
Let me phrase it in another way: lets say we have a vector space in 2D, that is defined by two vectors $e_\mathrm{1}$ and $e_\mathrm{2}$, and a point in space that is described by a combination:
     x$e_\mathrm{1}$+y$e_\mathrm{2}$

I want to describe that point by a different coordinate system, with two other vectors: $k_\mathrm{1}$ and $k_\mathrm{2}$ . Do they have to be mutually orthogonal?

Comment: Orthogonal to what? A single vector can't "be orthogonal". Two vectors can be orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Need not  be mutually orthogonal. For example, $(1,0)$ and $(\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5})$ are both unit vectors but not orthogonal.

Comment: orthogonal to what? a single vector may have norm one, in which case it is a unit vector, or it may have norm different than one, in which case it is not. For that purpose all you need is a normed space. You can't even ask if that vector, moreover, needs to be orthogonal. Orthogonality is a property of a pair of vectors in an inner product space.

Comment: Coordinate systems need not be orthonormal. In some contexts it is common to operate a restriction to those.

Comment: @TonyK, although this has nothing to do with the unit vectors, isn't the zero-vector orthogonal to itself, as well?

Comment: @Cheesecake Yes, orthogonal *to something*, that something being itself.

Comment: You seem to be misusing the term "unit vector". A unit vector is a vector with length $1$. But from the context, it looks to me as if "basis vector" is what you mean $-$ a vector that is an element of a basis (which is what you call a "coordinate system"). So perhaps your real question is "Must all the vectors in a basis be mutually orthogonal?" And the answer is no, as Yves Daoust explains.

Comment: Thank you TonyK, I think that is it.

Answer (score 1):

A coordinate system need not be orthogonal. It can be defined by unit vectors, but this does not yield any simplification (in particular, the expression of the dot product is cumbersome).

When a coordinate system is orthogonal, it is an asset that the vectors be unit as well.

But nothing is mandated.